# Question about meaning of "its built in safety feature"

Tags: sentence-meaning

> On Monday, Air Chief Marshal Angus Houston, who heads the agency co-ordinating the search, said it was time to deploy the Bluefin-21 to begin its search of the sea floor. It set off on its first mission on Monday night." After completing around six hours of its mission, Bluefin-21 exceeded its operating depth limit of 4,500m and **its built in safety feature returned it to the surface**," the Joint Agency Co-ordination Centre said in a statement.

*Its built*? What is it?

I may understand the meaning of safety feature, but it is very difficult to figure out what does "its built" mean.

Answer (score 4):

The phrase *built in* (often hyphenated when used as an adjective: *built-in*) refers to something installed into a product at the factory.

For example:

- an automobile might have *built-in airbags*
- a computer might have extra RAM built in (meaning you don't have to add it yourself)

In your sentence, the Bluefin-21 was designed so that, instead of exceeding its maximum depth, it would return to the surface. This feature was *built into* its software, apparently. Judging by this news story, that seems to have been a smart design decision.

The context of your question reminds me of Asimov's [three Laws of Robotics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Laws_of_Robotics).

Answer (score -1):

It’s an included feature (additional construction), which makes the device return to the surface.

Comment: what does built here mean? Different from feature? A million thanks.

Comment: it's built-in, which means included (incorporated)